# Angularjs ng-repeat must display only in a single <li>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat to display multiple projects. When I click **View Images** button it will display images inside that project.

The code works fine but it will add the html content of the images in all list of projects with a class ng-hide.

How can I display the ng-repeat of the images in a single **li** only in the lists of project

**projects.html**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in projects">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        <p><button ng-click="displayImages(item.id)">View Images</button></p>
        <div ng-include="/static/images.html"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**images.html**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="image in images">
        <p>{{ image.name }}</p>
        <img src="{{ image.src }}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.displayImages = function(pid){
    req = {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/api/v1/" + pid + "/",
    }
    $http(req).success(function(response, status){
        $scope.images = response;
    })
}
```

Comment: Question is not very clear.  What does `single <li>` mean? What is relationship between `projects` array and `images` array ? What does `displayImages()` do? SHow more code and update problem description to be more understandable

Comment: Show your controller, it's impossible to answer without seeing your scope construction. How do you link an image to a project ?

Comment: The problem is that all of the <li> in my ng-repeat of my projects have the html code of my images.html.. It's not display being displayed but when I inspect element the source it have the code. I want that, when I click the View Images button my images.html only render in the <li> where the button is being clicked..

Comment: I already updated my question. The only problem is that when I inspect element the source code, the images.html code display in all <li> of the ng-repeat projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a scope variable such as `activeProject` and use that as a conditional in the view. Will pass the whole `item` as argument of `displayImages()`. Use `ng-if` to compare `activeProject` to each `item`

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="item in projects">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        <p><button ng-click="displayImages(item)">View Images</button></p>
        <!--  add ng-if conditional -->
        <div ng-if="item == activeProject" ng-include="/static/images.html"></div>
</li>
```

JS

```
$scope.displayImages = function(project){
    var pid = project.id;
    req = {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/api/v1/" + pid + "/",
    }
    $http(req).success(function(response, status){
        // assign the active project
        $scope.activeProject = project;
        $scope.images = response;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use condition in image div to show proper project images.

**in projects.html:**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in projects">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        <p><button ng-click="displayImages(item.id)">View Images</button></p>
        <div ng-show="item.id === pid" ng-include="/static/images.html"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

also can use ***ng-if*** instead of ***ng-show***

**in images.html:**
as usual but you can yse use **ng-src** instead of **src**

**in controller:**:

```
$scope.displayImages = function(pid){
    $scope.pid = pid;
    req = {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/api/v1/" + pid + "/",
    }
    $http(req).success(function(response, status){
        $scope.images = response;
    })
};
```

Comment: no sense loading a ton of images though if they aren't needed. `ng-if` still better choice I think than `ng-show` for that reason

Comment: yep also use ng-if  if no need to render image.html first time. when click view images only condition satisfied project images.html render and when click another project view image then previous rendered images.html destroy.

Comment: not destroyed completely...they will still be in browser cache

Comment: may be but as far I know **it completely destroy from DOM element** and ng-If recreates elements using their compiled state.